# How to find text node in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a table with two columns. And i can't change it. In the left column there are checkboxes, their id's and names are made from this pattern - id="selected[0]" and so on.
In the right column there are only anchor tags with text inside.

I need to check if checkbox next to specific cell with specific text is checked or not.

Comment: You should show some markup, would make it a lot easier to visualize. Then also show the Javascript you have so far

Comment: Do provide markup please.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery to find a cell containing a specific text.

e.g. if text is 'hello world' than you can do a search for nodes and go to next element to it like this

```
var checkBox = $("td:contains('hello world')").next(); // to go to next, use prev() to go to previous element to the cell
var isChecked = checkBox.is(":checked"); // to check if checkbox is checked
```